# Incorrect image orientation when drawing a line with cv2.line

Tags: python, image, opencv, rotation

I want to draw a line from top left corner to the bottom right corner on an image.
The image is horizontal and:

```
print(size)
```

returns:

```
(203, 248)
```

With my code I am expecting a diagonal line from pixel (0,0) to pixel (203, 248). However I am getting diagonal line from pixel (0,0) to pixel (248, 203) which is outside the image boundary (sic!).
I suppose the `cv2.line` method rotates the image somehow, can anyone advise?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

image_1 = cv2.imread('profilowe.jpeg',0)
size = image_1.shape
print(size)
cv2.line(image_1,(0,0),image_1.shape,255,1,16)

cv2.imshow('image',image_1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Image with line incorrectly drawn on top]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because while NumPy indexes arrays based on a row-first principle (i.e. your shape is (rows, columns)), OpenCV indexes based on (x, y) co-ordinates, meaning the axes are flipped. This can be annoying to deal with, but this should fix your issue:

Try changing:

```
cv2.line(image_1, (0,0), image_1.shape, 255, 1, 16)
```

to

```
cv2.line(image_1, (0,0), image_1.shape[::-1], 255, 1, 16)
```

The `[::-1]` flips the tuple to become `(248, 203)`, and your line should look fine now.